# combining jquery selection to permorm operation on defined selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

### I have the following code:

```
$  (document).ready(function(){
  $('tr:nth-child(odd)').addClass("alt");
});
```

---

I want the `tr:nth-child(odd)` only to perform on table rows that begin with `'tr[id^="part"]'`.

How can I do this?  I am kind of new to this and could use some help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('tr[id^="part"]:nth-child(odd)').addClass("alt");
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xv3D7/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [multiple attribute](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/) selector:

```
$('tr[:nth-child(odd)][id^="part"]').addClass("alt");
```